# I'm worried about current in an inductor at $t=0$ when it is connected with a DC source

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

When I connect a dc battery to an ideal pure inductor i think the voltage across inductor should be infinity. Because the rate of change of current should be infinity.because in no time say in $0$ seconds the voltage rises from $0$ to $V$ (which is voltage of battery). But definitely this not happens. Can someone tell me what is happening at $t=0$?

Comment: Are the resistor and inductor connected in series or parallel?

Comment: So I see you tried to add in "and a resistor" to the question. Unfortunately that invalidates some answers that had already been posted before this edit. You should not edit questions such that current answers become invalid

Comment: Not me guv'nor. I just saw it and assumed you had written it.

Answer (score 2):

At t=0, there’s no current and the voltage across the inductor is the battery voltage.

The current in the inductor will rise linearly with time because inductor current is controlled by $V = L di/dt$. An inductor is not a resistor or wire, it’s it’s own kind of thing.

Eventually the current will start to get big.

A real battery has a maximum current it can provide. As more and more current is drawn from the battery, the battery voltage drops until finally the max current is reached. And at that point, with voltage across the inductor, the current stops changing.

Comment: Is the 'battery current limit' an example of RL circuit with DC source?

Answer (score 2):

You have an electric circuit like this:
[image: circuit]
<sub>(image from [Electronics tutorials: LR series circuit](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/lr-circuits.html))</sub>

It is described by the following equations for voltages and current
$$\begin{align}
V_R(t)&=RI(t) \\
V_L(t)&=L\frac{dI(t)}{dt} \\
V_S&=V_R(t)+V_L(t)
\end{align}$$
and the starting condition
$$I(0)=0.$$

These equations can be solved and the solution is
$$\begin{align}
I(t)&=\frac{V_S}{R}\left(1-e^{-Rt/L}\right) \\
V_L(t)&=V_S\ e^{-Rt/L} \\
V_R(t)&=V_S\left(1-e^{-Rt/L}\right)
\end{align}$$

[image: solution plot]
<sub>(image from [Electronics tutorials: LR series circuit](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/lr-circuits.html))</sub>

You see that the current $I(t)$ does not increase
to its final value in no time.
Instead of this you see:

- In the beginning (for $t\ll\frac{L}{R}$)
  the current increases almost linearly: $I(t)\approx\frac{V_S}{L}t$
- After a long time (for $t\gg\frac{L}{R}$)
  the current is almost constant: $I(t)\approx\frac{V_S}{R}$

At $t=0$, $\frac{dI(t)}{dt}$ (the rate of change of current) is not $\infty$.
Instead $\frac{dI(t)}{dt}$ changes from $0$ to $\frac{V_S}{L}$.
Therefore $V_L(t)$ changes from $0$ to $V_S$. Nothing dramatic happens here.

---

#### Edit (after question was changed to a version without a resistor in the circuit):

Without a resistor (i.e. $R=0$) the solution above reduces to
$$\begin{align}
I(t)&=\frac{V_S}{L}t \\
V_L(t)&=V_S \\
V_R(t)&=0
\end{align}$$

At $t=0$ the situation is the same as above with a resistor $R$.
Nothing dramatic happens here.

Comment: Note that I have rolled back the question to a previous version that does not have a resistor in the circuit, as the edit that invalidated other existing answers shouldn't have been done

Comment: @AaronStevens Thanks. I tried to amend my answer to the changed question.

Comment: Thanks! I feel like the OP is interested at $t=0$ where $\text dI/\text dt$ is discontinuous perhaps? Although they seem to think that the derivative becomes infinite, which is not the case in an RL circuit.

Comment: The diagram is almost correct, it just needs the $R$ putting next to the battery and relabelling $V_b$ or similar for its internal resistance. The analysis is basically the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the battery being current limited, it is also the case that "ideal inductors" do not exist. A real inductor will have some resistance (so that its impedance can be written as $Z = R_L + i \omega L$) as will the leads connecting it to the battery. These small resistances also act to limit the current surge when the inductor is connected.

Comment: This is in ac circuits. Impendance doesn't exist in dc circuits.

Comment: But the inductor will still have the resistance $R_L$ in a dc circuit.

Comment: Yes.The right part doesn't exist (ivL) in dc circuits.

Comment: @JellyStrawberry The rising current at switch-on is not DC

Comment: So can you define a frequency of the dc voltage source?

Comment: @hdhondt Isn't the rising current at switch-on an example of what is called 'variable DC'? As far as I know it is only called AC when the current changes direction/sign not when it changes in magnitude only.

Comment: Inductor does not have any eyes it cannot see that the "DCBATTERY" is written on the battery or not.

Comment: Inductor only watches changes in current and thus make a emf according to the change..

Comment: We all know that dc battery does not cause changing voltage  but    but   but   at t=0 the voltage suddenly changes from 0 to v . Only that part i m considering .

Comment: In reality the voltage will not instantly go from zero to V, this would violate relativity, therefore you are imagining a scenario which cannot exist

Comment: I agree more like of a mathematician than a physicist we have here...

Comment: The question specifically asks about an ideal inductor. For this, $Z=0$. Although, technically, Fourier analysis will reveal AC components in the waveform. this is classed as DC not AC because it is all in one direction and does not oscillate.

Comment: No, Z=0 would be a broken inductor, rather than an ideal one. But the OP seems worried about discontinuities in the current, so I'm just pointing out these arise from oversimplications of the system.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect a battery with the inductor there will be a sudden change in electric field at t=0 . That change in electric field will cause changing magnetic field which will cause the equal and opposite voltage in the inductor against the voltage source(according to faraday and lenz law). This induced voltage will oppose the rate of change of current. means that it will not stop the current but will limit the rate at which the current changes. That is the reason you dont get infinite current or voltage across the indutor. Rather you will get a constant rate of change/increase in current because of the opposing induced voltage.